# Changing the form of a tuple

Tags: haskell, tuples

I have a list of lists containing tuples. I want to change the form of the list I am receiving into a different form. Example below:

I am taking in 
`[[(String, Int, String, Int, String, Double)]]` or `[[(a,b,c,d,e,f)]]`

I want to turn it into a single list of tuples of the form:

`[(String,Double,Int)]` specifically `[(e, ((d*f)/(d)), d)]`

I am trying to calculate a GPA where the list contains a list of tuples that contain all the classes a person is taking. `e` is the name of the person, `d` is the number of credits, and `f` is the grade point. The name will be the same in each tuple, but the grade point and number of credits won't.

I don't understand how I can go through all of the tuples inside the list of lists and take the `d` and `f` of each tuple which are the values I need to calculate the GPA.

If any help could be given to push me in the right direction that would be appreciated.

Thank you

---

UPDATE

I am now at the point where I have a single list of tuples. Looks like this:

```
    [("Erikson,Ann",2.0,3),("Erikson,Ann",3.33,3),("Lewis,Buck",2.66,1), 
    ("Lewis,Buck",2.0,3),("Smith,John",0.0,1),("Smith,John",1.66,3), 
    ("Smith,John",1.33,3),("Torvell,Sarah",4.0,3)]
```

I need to create one tuple for each person. The tuple should have the form:
        (name, calculated gpa, total credits)

The calculated gpa is the 2nd element of each tuple multiplied by the 3rd element in each tuple added with the product of that same operation with all the other tuples that share the same name. then divide that number by the sum of the credits(the third element). The sum of all the third elements in tuples that share the same name is the third element. Confusing and hard to work. In the end i want one tuple for each person.

I am trying this:

```
    type MyType2 = (String, Double, Int)
    groupNameTuple :: MyType2 -> MyType2 -> Bool
    groupNameTuple (a,_,_) (b,_,_) = a==b


    calcGPA :: MyType2 -> MyType2 -> MyType2
    calcGPA (a,b,c) (d,e,f) = (a, ((b*c)+(e*f))/(b+e), (b+e))
```

When I try to do this calculation on the bottom it says the middle element isn't a double. Other than that error is this in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps the [join](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) function will help. It can take a list of lists and "flatten" it to a single list.

Comment: *I am trying* Can you show your attempts?

Comment: Step one is to write a function which transforms a single tuple, that is, a function of type `(String, Int, String, Int, String, Double) -> (String, Double, Int)`. Have you made an attempt at doing that? Show us how far you got!

Comment: Yes I currently have:



computeGpas = show . (map (map calcGPA) .groupBy groupName .sortBy byName) . (map stringToTuple) . (map words) . lines



calcGPA [[subject, num, section, credits, name, grade]] = (name,(grade*credits)/credits, credits)



This is what I have been trying to work with.

Thank you.
@DanielWagner

Answer (score 0):

First define a function to calculate GPA, e.g.:

`gpa (a,b,c,d,e,f) = (e,d*f/d,d)`

You'll want to map the list twice, first for the outer list and second for the inner lists, e.g.:

`fmap (fmap gpa) listOfLists`

Or using `<$>` operator:

`((<$>) gpa) <$> listOfLists`

An alternative prelude called [protolude](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/protolude) also defines an operator that does this and looks quite intuitive:

`gpa <<$>> listOfLists`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is *exactly* what you want based on your comment, but it may help:

```
convertTupleList :: [[(String, Int, String, Int, String, Double)]] -> [(String,Double,Int)]
convertTupleList ts = map morphTuple $ concat ts

morphTuple :: (String, Int, String, Int, String, Double) -> (String, Double, Int)
morphTuple (_,_,_,d,e,f) = (e, (d'*f)/d', d)
  where
    d' = fromIntegral d
```

`convertTupleList` first `concat`s the list of list of tuples, basically `[[a]]->[a]`. Then it `map`s the `morphTuple` function over the `concat`ed list. So each element is morphed from a tuple `(String,Int,String,Int,String,Double)` to `(String,Double,Int)`. The `morphTuple` function uses `fromIntegral` to convert `Int` to `Double` then multiplies and divides accordingly. There are certainly more cleaner solutions, for instance `convertTupleList` screams for point-free style but I'll leave it as an exercise to optimize and correct any specification errors. I would also advise dissecting the `concat` and `map` functions in GHCi. Further references and helpful list functions: [Haskell Report Folds](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch20.html#x28-23100020.3)

PS: Please add **coding attempts**  and updates to the original question with the edit button.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense and successfully converted the list into the form I am looking for. I'm still having issues with the math and calculating the GPA in code. I updated my post above with what I have tried. 
Thank you

Comment: @Riley use `fromIntegral` to convert from `Int` to `Double`. So in your update `c` and `f` are `Int`s that need to be `Double`. Haskell does not implicitly convert types. As briefly noted in my explanation you'll need to do this: `(b*(fromIntegral c)+e*(fromIntegral f))/(b+e)`. `b` and `e` are already of type `Double` and thus do not need conversion. You're going in the right direction. The reference I posted has many useful functions on lists such as `groupBy` and `map`, play around with them in GHCi to work out errors and construct more complex functions incrementally.